# Is this an incorrect practice of OO programming?

Tags: java

I'm working on re-writing a paint handler for my api. Is this incorrect practice of OO for my class structure of the PaintManager or is it fine? I feel like it's correct but I wanted some second opinions.

Ignore the height and positional values in the Background class. :p

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please get in a habit to post actual code instead of images. [See this answer as Why I'm saying this.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2815219)

Comment: I usually do, I just took the pictures for another purpose and then used them here. Sorry!

Comment: Is 'this' an incorrect practice? Is *what* an incorrect practice? Explain clearly what your question is.

Comment: @Sam As in, is this class structure for the PaintManager an incorrect Object Oriented programming practice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not an incorrect practice. Moreover, whatever you've implemented here is like a **Strategy Design Pattern**.

Strategy Pattern says
*capture the abstraction in an interface, bury implementation details in derived classes.*

[image: Strategy Design Pattern]

[source](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `PaintManager`, I assume that you will have a lot of classes implementing `Paintable`. Try to have your classes as general as possible, to avoid having to write too many classes.

If you created a `class Square extends Paintable` for example, the difference in the code would be minimal.

```
public class Square extends Paintable {
    // the x position
    private int x;

    // the y position
    private int y;

    // the width
    private int w;

    // the height
    private int h;

    // the color
    private Color color;

    public Square(int x, int y, int w, int h, Color color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.color = color;
    }

    // draw method
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color.getCOLOR());
        g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
        g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    }
}
```

Background can be an object of a more general class.

Read [Difference between an object and a class](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/difference-between-object-and-class/) for more details